# Custom map engine for Android

Tags: android, dictionary

I need to display a set of labeled markers on a scrollable and zoomable grid. Something like Google Maps Android API, but without actual map images, just the UI.

I'm using Google Maps with maps disabled, but it has a problem --- it cannot zoom below 5 metres, while I might need zoom down to millimeter scale (markers could be that close). Yandex Maps has similar limitation --- I cannot zoom beyond map resolution, even if I don't use it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, I just wrote my own component.

Comment: Can you shed more light on how you did this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot share code of my custom renderer, so here are general architecture:

1. A **MapView** (extends **View**) component with **pan** and **zoom** properties and list of **MapLayers**
2. A **MapLayer** abstract class with **onClick** and **render** methods. This class has two subclasses:

   2.1. A **GridLayer** class which **render** methods draws grid depending on **MapView**'s **pan** and **zoom**

   2.2. A **MarkerLayer** class which stores **Markers** and renders them.
3. **Marker** stores **latitude**, **longitude** and also HashMap of **attributes** (such as color, id etc)
4. To map **Marker**'s **latitude** and **longitude** to **MapView**'s x and y I use instance **IProjector** interface, currently - Mercator Projector with formulas from Wikipedia
5. To render **Marker**'s **MarkerLayer** uses instance of **MarkerRenderer** abstract class. I have two **MarkerRenderers**: **SimpleMarkerRenderer**, which draws circles (their stroke and fill colors are taken from **Marker**'s **attributes**), and **ImageMarkerRenderer**, which draws images (image ids taken from **Marker**'s **attributes**)